# Store image blob data into postgresql column with data type bytea

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert image blob data into a column of data type `bytea`.

The insert query is as follows:

```
insert into messages(message, thumbnail_blob)
values('DROPBOX', 
'00\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u000u0014P ��(\u0000��(\u0003��') 
returning id
```

I have cut short the blob data for understanding and formatting purposes.

After executing the above query, I get the error

Comment: why not saving  images in a file system (or NFS) and storing path in postgres? You will have smaller dump ...

Comment: @Renato storing in the app and storing the database is different, I dont want to store the files in the app memory .

Comment: You're right! I was thinking to a webapp not to an app!

Comment: @Renato , it's a web app , by app I meant the app server memory; i.e the RAM of the app .

Comment: Ok, as you want, we save them in a shared file sistem, but we have a lot of images and a db of 400 GB without them... little db, little dump, fast recovery but, probabily, this is not your need: it was just a suggest

Comment: Your question ends mid-sentence.  You didn't paste the error message.

Comment: You post has 6 weird characters that don't display properly for me.  Why aren't those in `\u` notation?  Perhaps that could be the problem?

Comment: @jjanes I just pasted the some part of the image blob data for understanding to the people. And for the \u part , its a part of the image blob data

Comment: I'm not asking where the `\u` comes from, I'm asking why it isn't being used for 6 random characters which seem to need it.

Comment: @jjanes, I dont know about it, I just pasted the query which was being executed  by the node postgres driver